# Error when getting dependencies Ionic Framework 2

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, npm, ionic2, npm-install

I'm getting an error while trying to get the dependencies of Ionic Framework 2. I'm working on Visual Studio 2015.

This is the error that I'getting when I try to restore the dependencies:

```
====Executing command 'npm install'====
znpm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/angular/compiler
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/angular/common
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/angular/compiler-cli
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/sw-toolbox
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic-angular
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/angular/core
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/zone.js
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/angular/forms
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/angular/http
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/angular/platform-browser
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/angular/platform-browser-dynamic
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/angular/platform-server
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic/storage
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic/app-scripts
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/typescript
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/sw-toolbox
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic-angular
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/zone.js
npm http 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/angular/common
npm ERR! 404 Not Found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'angular/common' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'io.cordova.myappf8082c'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\Microsoft\\Web Tools\\External\\\\node\\node" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\Microsoft\\Web Tools\\External\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\jonat\OneDrive\documentos\visual studio 2015\Projects\Bcons\Bcons
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! code E404
npm http 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/angular/core
npm http 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/angular/compiler
npm http 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/angular/compiler-cli
npm http 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/angular/forms
npm http 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/angular/platform-browser-dynamic
npm http 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/angular/platform-server
npm http 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/angular/http
npm http 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/angular/platform-browser
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/typescript
npm http 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic/storage
npm http 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic/app-scripts
npm

====npm command completed with exit code 1====
```

The only dependencies that appear as *not installed* are:

- ionic-angular
- rxjs
- sw-toolbox
- typescript
- zone.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and update your npm and node first.
`npm -v 1.4.9` is old.
Do

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

It probably does not have the latest registry

Comment: Are you able to ping the registry url?  If not it could be some network issue.. Maybe a proxy?

Comment: Unable to ping any url.